# get object of returned mongoose find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi i'm trying to access the elements returned from a find in mongoose and having some trouble with the asynchronous and callback situation.

Here is the code for better understanding.

```
function retrieveBudgets(email, callback) {
        models.User.find({email: email},{budget:true}, function(err,budgets) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, budgets);
        }
    });
};

retrieveBudgets(user.email, function(err, budgets) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    budgets.forEach(function(budget){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(budget, null, 4));
    });

});
```

So this line `console.log(JSON.stringify(budget, null, 4));` is working correctly and printing the objects to screen in json format but how do I store each to an array of objects from here? if I try to push to an array at this same line I get an error.

I have seen some questions that are similar but i am not getting any headway with them.
EDIT:____________________________________________________________
I did a little hack to get it working, i moved res.render up, so that rendering the page was done at the same time as the callback but I cant see this being the right solution any thoughts

```
    var user=req.session.user;
    res.locals.budgets=[];

    function retrieveBudgets(email, callback) {
        models.User.find({email: email},{budget:true}, function(err, budgets) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err, null);
            } else {
                callback(null, budgets);
            }
        });
    };

    retrieveBudgets(user.email, function(err, budgets) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
            res.locals.budgets = budgets.map((function(b){ return b; });

        res.render('budget/budget.jade',{ csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
    });
```

This works I can access budgets through locals so any feedback on this would be great I doubt its the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `budgets` return value that you get from the `retrieveBudgets` call is already an array.

this is evidenced by your call to `budgets.forEach` which is a method on arrays.

is there a specific need to create a new array from the items? that can be easily done:

`var myNewArray = budgets.map((function(b){ return b; });`

this one line of code will [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the original budgets array into a new array containing each of the budget items.

there are other methods of creating a new array, depending on what you need to do exactly

**update from comments below**

> what i really want to do to is use the budgets outside of the query so I can pass it to the view

in that case, you need to render the view from within the callback and pass the budgets to the view:

```
router.get("/foo", function(req, res, next){

  retrieveBudgets(user.email, function(err, budgets) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.render('budget/budget.jade',{ 
      budgets: budgets,
      csrfToken: req.csrfToken() 
    });
  });

});
```

This is the only, and correct, way to make this work.

If you tried to do it without waiting for the callback to finish, you would not have any data in your `budgets` array. Therefore, you must wait for the callback to be executed and then render your view with the `budgets` (or single `budget` or whatever) passed to the view.

(There are variations of this using promises, but I find callbacks to be the easier way to handle this.)

Comment: I thought i had it but when i try to use myNewArray outside it gives me undefined, even if declare it within the scope, what i really want to do to is use the budgets outside of the query so I can pass it to the view

Answer (score 1):

Turn the line in which you're passing an object to your jade file

```
res.render('budget/budget.jade',{
  csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), 
  budgets: budgets.map(function(b) {return b;})
});
```

This will pass `budgets` to your jade file, and you should be able to access it there.